# How to test against values in request.getHeader using jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, user-agent

Im setting up a variable:

```
<% String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");%>
```

How do I test different scenarios against userAgent using

```
<c:choose></c:choose>
```

Im not sure how to set it up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to mix *scriptlets* with taglibs/EL. They do not run in the same scope.

All request headers are in EL available by an implicit mapped object `${header}`. Since the `user-agent` header name contains a special character `-` so that `${header.user-agent}` don't work as expected, you need to use the brace notation `[]` which quotes it.

```
${header['user-agent']}
```

So, this should do:

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(header['user-agent'], 'Gecko')}">
        You're pretending to use a Gecko based browser.
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(header['user-agent'], 'MSIE')}">
        You're pretending to use a MSIE based browser.
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(header['user-agent'], 'Webkit')}">
        You're pretending to use a Webkit based browser.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        It's not clear which browser you're pretending to use.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the problem: checking the user agent header this way is a code smell. The user agent header is fully controlled by the client and can easily be spoofed into a completely different value (that's why I used the term "pretending" in the above code example). How to solve the real functional requirement properly, you'd like to elaborate a bit more about the real functional requirement.

For example, in JavaScript you should prefer [feature detection](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/) over browser detection.

Or when you'd like to load specific stylesheets based on the media type, you should rather use the [`media` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen,projection,tv" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smartphone.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:480px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" media="handheld" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Or when you'd like to present the enduser an user-friendly summary of the information found in the user agent header, you'd like to use a separate service instead such as http://user-agent-string.info/. They also offer a [Java API example](http://user-agent-string.info/api/xmlrpc-java-example).

Comment: What do you mean by code smell? This seemed like a good way to detect for iphone/android as user-agent and therefore inject stylesheets targeted towards these mobile platforms. Would you suggest something different?

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I will try the stylesheet approach first.

Comment: I updated the answer, the `smartphone.css` in the example should be what you need for iPhone/Android.

Comment: Good point noting that EL and scriptlets don't run within the same scope!